# Bitwise functions and concatenating hex strings

Tags: python

I'm testing some of the functionality of bitwise functions in python. I want to see if I can concatenate hex "strings" as a converted integer and save as a new hex string after applying logical bitwise operations.

```
def hst(self):
    ref = 0
    href = ['1b','1bfa','001','0010']
    for i in range(0,len(href)):
        if i > 0:
            ref = ref << len(href[i])*4
            ref = ref ^ int(href[i],16)
        else:
            ref = int(href[i],16)
    return hex(ref)
```

I expect 1b1bfa0010010 but I get fa0001010.
Any thoughts as to why and how I might fix this? As I said, I'm just trying to learn how this all works. I don't wish to use any libraries, just what is included without an import statement.

It's not doing the shifting. I see from the `print(hex(ref))`:

```
shift: 0x1b00
xor: 0xfa
shift: 0xfa0000
xor: 0xfa0001
shift: 0xfa0001000
xor: 0xfa0001010
```

shift is happening but not correctly xoring to the right place.

OMG Windows, you suck! I get the wrong answer in windows only. Linux it works. Why does Windows suck so much?! Thank you both for helping!

Comment: I'm getting `'0x1b1bfa0010010L'` when I call it - should be correct.

Comment: However, you can add a `print hex(ref)` in the loop to see how `ref` changes each step.

Comment: I see the expected [`0x1b1bfa0010010`](http://ideone.com/3UtoXA). It [works on Python 2 too](http://ideone.com/hxfykl).

Comment: I'm running in windows, could that be the reason? @J.F. Sebastian @ 0605002

Comment: I see nothing Windows specific in the code. It might be 32bit vs. 64bit difference due to a bug on old Python version. Are you on 32bit system? What is your Python version?

Comment: Im running python 3.4 on both Linux and windows in a 32bit linux and 64bit windows OS

Comment: [ideone uses Linux](http://ideone.com/cdQBFB). I've tried your code on py26, py27, py32, py33, py34, pypy, jython (corresponds to Python 2.5) and it works (Linux 64bit). There is no `int()` vs. `long()` on Python 3.4 therefore it also is not a reason. [It also works on repl.it](http://repl.it/1Zq).

Comment: The output I'm getting doesn't lie though. It doesn't appear to do the same thing in windows python 3.4 that it does in linux python 3.4. I posted the progression through the program above and the program is the same and obviously running in 3.4 as I didn't change formats or add lines for version support (i.e. __future__)